# Why can one misbehaving program hang the whole system?

Tags: performance

Often my computer run out of memory or has one very heavy script (let's say a machine learning training or a simple DB import) that hangs the whole system. I can't move the mouse or interact with the OS (except via magic keys).

Shouldn't the system always be smooth even if some program is doing crazy things ? A bit like having a misbehaving website in a browser.

I know this is a bit too generic, I just want to know if this is supposed to happens / this was a conscious decision / an hard theorical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the resources consumed by your script this could very well be a "normal" behaviour. You can try to `renice` the process(es) to a lower priority and if the IO is at fault see `ionice`.

Comment: Thanks but when the computer is already hanged up, I can't use `nice` anymore. Maybe the solution is to put all new programs as 'low' priority by default except for the DM ?

Comment: Try to open couple of terminal windows and run ```top``` in one of them and ```iotop -o``` in the other hopefully you will be able to see what's going on when you start your script then.

Answer (score 1):

From a design (i.e. conscious decision) standpoint there are four reasons why a misbehaving program could be allowed to hang the whole system.

1. The operating system's hardware requirements would be too large otherwise, forcing the user to buy additional hardware that he doesn't need.
2. The operating system itself would be too large otherwise.
3. The operating system would be a resource hog otherwise.
4. The operating system would be inefficient about energy usage otherwise.

Corollaries:

1. Ubuntu does not hang as often when running on hardware with a faster processor, more RAM, an SSD instead of an HDD, etc.
2. In general newer operating systems that are designed to run well on new hardware hang less than older operating systems that are designed to be compatible with the limitations of old hardware.